# Regex That Pulls Certain Bits From a String

Tags: regex, powershell

So I am trying to work with Regular Expression the string I have is

```
Successfully created package 'C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage\AjaxControlToolkit.3.5.50401.nupkg'
```

I am trying to make a regular expression that pulls "Successfully" and "C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage\AjaxControlToolkit.3.5.50401.nupkg"

I haven't used Regular Expression a lot and what I'm doing isn't working, what I have so far is

```
'.*(Successfully\.*\C\D+).*', '$1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(\S*)\s.*'(.*)'$
```

- #1 match is the status
- #2 match is the path

https://regex101.com/r/eC7vX1/1

Powershell:

```
$line = "Successfully created package 'C:\Users\mhopper\Documents\CreateNugetPackage\AjaxControlToolkit.3.5.50401.nupkg'"
$values = $line -split "^(\S*)\s.*'(.*)'$"
$status = $values[1]
$path = $values[2]
("status:{0}\npath:{1}" -f $status,$path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a little more specific about why you need the regex.

Just getting those two values from the string doesn't really need a regex.

```
$Status,$PackagePath = ($String.Trim().Split(' ',4))[0,3]
```

Comment: Would `[0,-1]` be better in case of other words appearing in the middle.

Comment: It would fail if the path would contain spaces in it. You would split the package path in the middle, and get only last/ selected part of it.

Comment: @BartekB - $true.  But you can take care of that by specifying the split count. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Matt - Maybe.  But there's no indication in the question that any other text patterns are involved.